# I changed the session cookie name in my django project and I am unable to login

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication, django-settings, django-sessions

I want to change the SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN because it's set incorrectly on a production server. Due to this, I also need to change the SESSION_COOKIE_NAME to something else. Otherwise, there'll be two cookies with the same name and different domains on the user's side, because it's already in production. With these two cookies, the user will have trouble logging in.

This would normally be fine, but now the problem.

Just after I changed the SESSION_COOKIE_NAME (so I haven't even changed the SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN yet), I am unable to login into the admin console. I can see the cookie with the new name being set. The application itself has no problems and users can login without problems, which is strange because it's the same authentication.

What I've tried:

Deleting all sessions on the server site
Private mode
Other Browser
Flushing all possible caches on the server but might have missed one.
Checking for hardcoded session names, but there are not.
What else could I possibly check? If I set the SESSION_COOKIE_NAME back to what it was, I can log in again. This issue only happens on the production server; not locally, and not on the test server, which makes it hard to test.

Any ideas?